# Signing an iPhone Xcode project using scripts (commandline)

Tags: iphone, ipad, shell, command-line, sign

I would like to sign an iPhone Xcode project using only commands (I would use it in the future to integrate it with Jenkins or something similar). How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `xcrun`. Examples [here](http://skabber.com/package-your-ios-application-with-xcrun) and [here](http://blog.octo.com/en/automating-over-the-air-deployment-for-iphone/).